# LAN not working while laptop on battery

Tags: 13.04, laptop, battery, lan

My wired LAN is not working when my laptop is on battery - anyone out there who knows where to look for a solution?

Strange thing is, that the LAN port is not entirely switched off, as there's light in the link and activity LEDs, it just doesn't work when the laptop is on battery - but the wireless LAN is working fine...

Comment: I have a similar situation. If I'm using the battery and disconnect the ethernet cable, it won't reconnect if I plug the cable again until I connect the power cable. Maybe it's related to [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1112652).

Comment: There is a workaround: `sudo echo on | sudo tee /sys/class/net/eth0/device/power/control` might reenable the ethernet port.